# Can average rate of change be represented by a vector?

Tags: multivariable-calculus

Usually we think of rates of change as scalars. However, if $\vec r(t)$ is a vector--valued function on $[t_0,t_1]$, does not $\displaystyle\frac{\vec r(t_1)-\vec r(t_0)}{t_1-t_0}$, which is a vector, measure its "average rate of change on $[t_0,t_1]$"?

This seems correct, yet also feels very odd. Is it correct?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is fine.  Why does it feel odd?.  You can also write it componentwise and take the time derivative of each component.

Comment: I guess since I always think of rate of change as a scalar. I like being able to refer to it as a vector as it makes sense to me and makes other things work out well. It just seems nonstandard, and a colleague agreed. So I asked. Thanks.

Comment: Certainly it makes sense to talk of average velocity over a span of time. It is the velocity that, if held constant for a span of time, produces the observed displacement.